# C++ shared library undefined reference

Tags: c++, linux, reference, g++, undefined

i'm having something like these files:

libfoo.h

```
class foo
{
public:
foo() = default;
virtual ~foo();
};
```

libfoo.cpp

```
#include "libfoo.h"

foo::~foo() { /* code here */ }
```

test.cpp

```
#include <libfoo.h>
int main()
{
   foo f;
}
```

i compile libfoo.h and libfoo.cpp into a shared library and all that is fine. 
but when i then try to use the library in test.cpp i get undefined reference to the destructor ~foo().

this error however does not occur if i define the destructor directly in libfoo.h. i have this problem with all functions defined outside the class in my library so im guessing it has something to do with the compilation process (it compiles fine however)

i compile the library like this:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -c -o libfoo.o libfoo.cpp
g++ -shared libfoo.o -o libfoo.so
```

any ideas as to what i might be doing wrong?
(all the functions that i declare inclass, like template functions works fine and causes no undefined reference)

Comment: It this typo in your real code? `foo:~foo()`

Comment: Should be foo::~foo() { /* code here */ }

Comment: sorry, that typo occured when i typed the code here only

Comment: @Henningsson How do you link when you *use* the library?

Comment: -lfoo, the linking works properly which i can see from using ldd on a executable that is successfully compiled ( not calling any of the funtions causing problems )

Comment: ‘The linking works properly‘, so what is the problem, then?!

Comment: I assume he meant that linking "works" if he is not trying to use anything from the lib.

Comment: well, no. I can use some things from the library. just not classes that have definitions outside their .h file. the constructor in this example works etc

Comment: @Henningsson So when do you get the error? In your IDE? When you link? When you run?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error, but I failed.

I created the files (with slight modifications):

```
// libfoo.h
struct foo { virtual ~foo(); };
```

---

```
// libfoo.cpp
#include "libfoo.h"
foo::~foo() {}
```

---

```
// test.cpp
#include "libfoo.h"
int main() { foo f; }
```

Built like this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -c -o libfoo.o libfoo.cpp
$ g++ -shared libfoo.o -o libfoo.so
$ g++ test.cpp -L. -lfoo
```

And ran like this:

```
$ env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
```

I got no errors. Are you sure there is a problem with your code?